# Problems implementing ValidatingAntiForgeryToken attribute for Web API with MVC 4 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

I'm making JSON-based AJAX requests and, with MVC controllers have been very grateful to Phil Haack for his [Preventing CSRF with AJAX](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx) and, Johan Driessen's [Updated Anti-XSRF for MVC 4 RC](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Updated-Anti-XSRF-Validation-for-ASP.NET-MVC-4-RC). But, as I transition API-centric controllers to Web API, I'm hitting issues where the functionality between the two approaches is markedly different and I'm unable to transition the CSRF code.

ScottS raised a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken) recently which was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483099/609290) by Darin Dimitrov. Darin's solution involves implementing an authorization filter which calls AntiForgery.Validate. Unfortunately, this code does not work for me (see next paragraph) and - honestly - is too advanced for me.

As I understand it, Phil's solution overcomes the problem with MVC AntiForgery when making JSON requests in the absence of a form element; the form element is assumed/expected by the AntiForgery.Validate method. I *believe* that this may be why I'm having problems with Darin's solution too. I receive an HttpAntiForgeryException "The required anti-forgery form field '__RequestVerificationToken' is not present". I am certain that the token is being POSTed (albeit in the header per Phil Haack's solution). Here's a snapshot of the client's call:

```
$token = $('input[name=""__RequestVerificationToken""]').val();
$.ajax({
    url:/api/states",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
    headers: { __RequestVerificationToken: $token }
}).done(function (json) {
    ...
});
```

I tried a hack by mashing together Johan's solution with Darin's and was able to get things working but am introducing HttpContext.Current, unsure whether this is appropriate/secure and why I can't use the provided HttpActionContext.

Here's my inelegant mash-up.. the change is the 2 lines in the try block:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    try
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
    }
    catch
    {
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
            RequestMessage = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request
        };
        return FromResult(actionContext.Response);
    }
    return continuation();
}
```

My questions are:

- Am I correct in thinking that Darin's solution assumes the existence of a form element?
- What's an elegant way to mash-up Darin's Web API filter with Johan's MVC 4 RC code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the FromResult?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could try reading from the headers:

```
var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
var cookie = headers
    .GetCookies()
    .Select(c => c[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName])
    .FirstOrDefault();
var rvt = headers.GetValues("__RequestVerificationToken").FirstOrDefault();
AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, rvt);
```

Note: `GetCookies` is an extension method that exists in the class `HttpRequestHeadersExtensions` which is part of `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`. It will most likely exist in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`

Comment: Hey... What about `GetCookies()` method? How we have to implement it in general?

Comment: From [MVC Source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryTokenStore.cs), I have seen that they are using `httpContext.Request.Form[_config.FormFieldName]` in the GetFormToken method. Is there any reason why to not use Request.Params to access both form & header values? I think it may also include cookie :(. However they could check the request header when the Form is not available...

Comment: The HttpRequestHeadersExtensions DLL, System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, also comes from the Nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.

Comment: Likewise, AntiForgery and AntiForgeryConfig come from System.Web.WebPages.dll which is in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages nuget package.

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to add that this approach worked for me also (.ajax posting JSON to a Web API endpoint), although I simplified it a bit by inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute and overriding the OnActionExecuting method.

```
public class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var cookieName = AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName;
            var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
            var cookie = headers
                .GetCookies()
                .Select(c => c[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName])
                .FirstOrDefault();
            var rvt = headers.GetValues("__RequestVerificationToken").FirstOrDefault();
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, rvt);
        }
        catch
        {               
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Unauthorized request.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method using Darin's answer, with a check for the presence of the header.  The check means that the resulting error message is more indicative of what's wrong ("The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.") versus "The given header was not found."

```
public static bool IsHeaderAntiForgeryTokenValid(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    try
    {
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = request.Headers;
        CookieState cookie = headers
                .GetCookies()
                .Select(c => c[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName])
                .FirstOrDefault();

        var rvt = string.Empty;
        if (headers.Any(x => x.Key == AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName))
            rvt = headers.GetValues(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName).FirstOrDefault();

        AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, rvt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.LogError(ex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

ApiController Usage:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    if (Request.IsHeaderAntiForgeryTokenValid())
        return Ok();
    else
        return BadRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation using AuthorizeAttribute:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  public class ApiValidateAntiForgeryToken : AuthorizeAttribute {
    public const string HeaderName = "X-RequestVerificationToken";

    private static string CookieName => AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName;

    public static string GenerateAntiForgeryTokenForHeader(HttpContext httpContext) {
      if (httpContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
      }

      // check that if the cookie is set to require ssl then we must be using it
      if (AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl && !httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot generate an Anti Forgery Token for a non secure context");
      }

      // try to find the old cookie token
      string oldCookieToken = null;
      try {
        var token = httpContext.Request.Cookies[CookieName];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token?.Value)) {
          oldCookieToken = token.Value;
        }
      }
      catch {
        // do nothing
      }

      string cookieToken, formToken;
      AntiForgery.GetTokens(oldCookieToken, out cookieToken, out formToken);

      // set the cookie on the response if we got a new one
      if (cookieToken != null) {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, cookieToken) {
          HttpOnly = true,
        };
        // note: don't set it directly since the default value is automatically populated from the <httpCookies> config element
        if (AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl) {
          cookie.Secure = AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl;
        }
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
      }

      return formToken;
    }


    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
      if (HttpContext.Current == null) {
        // we need a context to be able to use AntiForgery
        return false;
      }

      var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
      var cookies = headers.GetCookies();

      // check that if the cookie is set to require ssl then we must honor it
      if (AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) {
        return false;
      }

      try {
        string cookieToken = cookies.Select(c => c[CookieName]).FirstOrDefault()?.Value?.Trim(); // this throws if the cookie does not exist
        string formToken = headers.GetValues(HeaderName).FirstOrDefault()?.Trim();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieToken) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(formToken)) {
          return false;
        }

        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
      }
      catch {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then just decorate your controller or methods with [ApiValidateAntiForgeryToken]

And add to the razor file this to generate your token for javascript:

```
<script>
var antiForgeryToken = '@ApiValidateAntiForgeryToken.GenerateAntiForgeryTokenForHeader(HttpContext.Current)';
// your code here that uses such token, basically setting it as a 'X-RequestVerificationToken' header for any AJAX calls
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, in .net core, the header's default value is actually just "RequestVerificationToken", without the "__". So if you change the header's key to that instead, it'll work.

You can also override the header name if you like:

`services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "__RequestVerificationToken")`