# Anti-Forgery Token + Web API (- MVC)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

How to use Anti-Forgery Token With ASP.NET Web API without ASP.NET MVC?

Stephen Walther has this article of "Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery Attacks with ASP.NET MVC" in http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/03/05/security-issues-with-single-page-apps ... but his solution includes MVC/Razor and in my front-end I don't planning to include it. And there are abundance articles like it, which the solution is adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` but this cannot be my solution.

Later, I solved another issue, "the Same Origin policy": http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api, Could this be the solution to prevent the CSRF as well? I don't think so.

Comment: This is what I ended doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that I did not want to use MVC and just serve static html files backed by a WebApi.   Here is what I did (Would this work?)  Create a Http module that sets a random cookie value when serving any static file.  For example:

```
public class XSRFModule : IHttpModule {
    ...

    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path) == ".html") {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("XSRF-TOKEN", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your html page, use javascript to add the cookie value to a header when calling your api:

```
function callApi() {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "api/data", true);
        var regex = /\b(?:XSRF-TOKEN=)(.*?)(?=\s|$)/
        var match = regex.exec(document.cookie);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", match[1]);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

finally, in your `HttpModule`, check that the cookie matches the header before processing any calls to your api:

```
void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.StartsWith("/api"))
        {
            string fromCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("XSRF-TOKEN").Value;
            string fromHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"];
            if (fromCookie != fromHeader)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to set the `HttpOnly` flag to `FALSE` so that javascript from your domain can read the cookie and set the header.   I am not a security expert, so I would like some feedback on this solution from some other members of the community.

**EDIT**

If you are using OWIN, you can use a global action Filter along with a middleware plugin:

Startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
            OnPrepareResponse = (responseContext) => {
                responseContext.OwinContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            },
            FileSystem = "wwwroot"
        });
```

XsrfFilter.cs

```
public class XsrfFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext) {

        string fromCookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("XSRF-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault()["XSRF-TOKEN"].Value;
        string fromHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("X-XSRF-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault();

        if (fromCookie == fromHeader) return;

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = "bad request";
    }
}
```