# AntiForgery Token implementation in WebAPI+AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

I have an HTMl app, which uses Web API and AngularJS. We are planing to implement AntiForgery token in the App. I have an Index.cshtml page in which I have added these code

```
@using System.Web.Helpers

@functions{
    public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}
```

And added an input tag like this:

```
  <input id="antiForgeryToken" data-ng-model="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" 
     data-ng-init="antiForgeryToken='@GetAntiForgeryToken()'" />
```

When I run the app, I am getting this error:

Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery' does not contain a definition for 'GetTokens'

ref : [Web API and ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken)

Can anyone advice?

What am I missing? 
Or is there a better way to implement Antiforgery token validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing a reference but don't use hidden input. Add the AntiForgeryToken to the Header instead.

Client can simply request the token via a custom HtmlHelper and add it to the Request Header when the view is initialized:

```
@Html.RequestVerificationToken()
```

And the Action retrieves it and validates it.

The easiest way is to create an AntiForgeryValidate attribute to your Post Action that validates the token from the header request.

```
[AntiForgeryValidate]
```

Have a look at this:

http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/

Comment: I have gone through the link. Issue I find is, where to add the MVC HTML Helper Extension? My client is a pure html+AngulaJS project.

Comment: @Html refers to HtmlHelper class which is a C# class so if you don't have access to C# and ASP.NET MVC, you can't take this approach. It should be extended on the server side.

Comment: I created a wrapper class. I added a cs file to the app, where I wrote the GetToken() method and then I called it from my cshtml. Through that, I was able to overcome the dll issue. For everything I did what the blog said and it works fine :)

Comment: Hi Vipin, Can you please provide more details on how the issue is resolved without @Html.RequestVerificationToken() line?
I am looking for a way to achieve this but since its just pure HTML I am unable to figure out how to achieve this.