# What is the difference between using AuthorizeAttribute or IAuthorizationFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute, iauthorizationfilter

AuthorizeAttribute requires you to override the OnAuthorization method and IAuthorizationFilter requires you to implement an OnAuthorization method.  Seems like the same thing to me, are there any other differences?  Why would one be used over the other?

EDIT:
To clarify, I'm trying to understand what the difference is between the following 2 pieces of code.

```
public class PasswordExpirationCheckAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private int _maxPasswordAgeInDays;

    public PasswordExpirationCheckAttribute(int maxPasswordAgeInDays)
    {
        _maxPasswordAgeInDays = maxPasswordAgeInDays;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BypassPasswordExpirationCheckAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            IPrincipal userPrincipal = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (userPrincipal != null && userPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userStore = new ApplicationUserStore(new IdentityDb());
                var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
                var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Result;

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var timeSpan = DateTime.Today.Date - user.LastPasswordChangedDate.Date;
                    if (timeSpan.TotalDays >= _maxPasswordAgeInDays)
                    {
                        HttpContextBase httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBase, new RouteData());
                        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);

                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("ChangePassword", "Manage"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }            

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and...

```
public class PasswordExpirationCheckAttribute : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private int _maxPasswordAgeInDays;

    public PasswordExpirationCheckAttribute(int maxPasswordAgeInDays)
    {
        _maxPasswordAgeInDays = maxPasswordAgeInDays;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BypassPasswordExpirationCheckAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            IPrincipal userPrincipal = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (userPrincipal != null && userPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userStore = new ApplicationUserStore(new IdentityDb());
                var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
                var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Result;

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var timeSpan = DateTime.Today.Date - user.LastPasswordChangedDate.Date;
                    if (timeSpan.TotalDays >= _maxPasswordAgeInDays)
                    {
                        HttpContextBase httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                        RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBase, new RouteData());
                        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);

                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("ChangePassword", "Manage"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }            

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you notice `AuthorizeAttribute` implements `IAuthorizationFilter`. One is an interface and the other a class.

Comment: @Shoe thanks for your reply. I understand that one is an interface and the other is class (though I overlooked that AuthrozieAttribute implemented that inteface). My question is more in regards to the implementation of an action filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IAuthorizationFilter` is only an interface.  It does nothing.  If you wanted to use it, you'd have to implement your own authorization attribute that implements that interface from the ground up.

`AuthorizeAttribute`, on the other hand, works out of the box.  It implements `IAuthorizationFilter` and already takes care of the common needs of developers.  It still allows you to override the `OnAuthorization` method in case you want to extend its functionality, but you don't have to, as it works just fine without you doing that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "works out of the box"?  If I create an IAuthorizationFilter and register it via FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters it still gets called on every action without needing to do anything else.  I have edited the question to include some code snippets.

Comment: In your examples, you are creating a net-new authorization filter, so I'd go with the interface.  You don't really gain anything by using AuthorizeAttribute as the base class in your case.  AuthorizeAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) allows you to limit access based on users/roles without having to make your own authorization filter (that's what I meant by out of the box)

Comment: ahhh ok makes sense now, that's what I assumed you meant but wanted to make sure. thanks for the help.