# What are the artifacts, to provide security to web api in asp.net?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api

Everywhere we need security in this web world. How can we provide the security to our asp.net Web api. what are the parameters for providing the security in terms of direct attack on web api to hack server data. What are the best practices and approach to provide security to Web API in dot net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you need to take into consideration when you want to secure your Web API.

Using transport encryption ([https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)) will provide you with server identity and confidentiality of the communication.

Authentication and authorization will provide you the ability to only serve data the users are allowed to access. Web API is most commonly secured with bearer tokens, either provided by an external authority or the application itself.

You also need to protect yourself against all kinds of common attacks:

- [Cross site request forgery (CSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)
- [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

ASP.NET Web API escapes data written to the output by default, mitigating some SQL injection attacks. It also has [mitigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken) for CSRF attacks built in.

See [security testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_testing) on wikipedia for more information.