# How to authenticate a web service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httprequest

after adding url to service reference in C#.net project I am able to access the different methods of the services , the service provider has given me the username and password for authentication ,however while accessing properties I didn't get the fields/properties for username and password (headers). So my question is that how to authenticate such web services?

----------------------------------------code------------------------------------------------------

```
queryNniNameType obj = new queryNniNameType();

reqtype = new queryNameAvailabilityRequestType();
headerType = new CNR.ServiceReference1.businessDocumentHeaderType();
businessbody = new queryNniNameType(); 

headerType.messageType = "test";
headerType.messageVersion = 2;
headerType.senderType ="sendertype";
headerType.senderId = "381133334535055664"; 
businessbody.proposedName = "asdfsf";  

reqtype.businessDocumentHeader = headerType;
reqtype.businessDocumentBody = businessbody;


nameAvailabilityResponseType nptype = new nameAvailabilityResponseType();
businessDocumentHeaderType bustype = new businessDocumentHeaderType();
req = new ExternalQueryNameAvailabilityClient();

reply = new queryNameAvailabilityReplyType();
reply.businessDocumentBody = nptype;
reply.businessDocumentHeader = bustype;
```

So where to pass username and password??

Comment: Please show some code for making the request without authentication.

Comment: are you using asmx web services?

Comment: Yes,I am using Soap based web services ,I am just accessing 3rd party services

Comment: @Codor I have given the code Please refer that

Comment: Perhaps the answer below ist just right; is this WCF? It seems so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like this in WCF Service:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

and for web service use client's Credentials property instead.

Answer (score 0):

To providing security to web services and web api almost same thing. 
Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247333/what-are-the-artifacts-to-provide-security-to-web-api-in-asp-net)
I asked before few days and got approach.