# How to implement AntiForgery token in device oriented web api?

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5, antiforgerytoken

Implementing the AntiForgery token system for the web API application.The scenario is, Its the project for Mobile application. So there is no MVC web application as of now. By following the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken) (answered),we can validate AntiForgery token. But unable to understand how to generate AntiForgery token for device request, how to initiate request for device and how it will be sequenced?