# write single API accessible through asp.net identity user and bearer token both

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib

I have created asp.net mvc 6 application and configured asp.net identity users using entity framework 7 working fine. Then I added  `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` token provider server that is also working fine.

Then I created an api controller as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [Authorize(Policy = "SomePolicy")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Question:
I want to configure authorization in such a way so that either bearer token or asp.net identity user is valid (and belong to some role), I want to allow the user to access API.

Here is what I tried in startup.cs:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                // Add a new policy requiring a "scope" claim
                // containing the "api-resource-controller" value.
                options.AddPolicy("API", policy => {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Scope, "offline_access");                                        
                });                
            });
```

then if I add `[Authorize(Policy="API")]` to my api controller, that is ONLY respecting bearer tokens, not identity users.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes` supports multiple schemes, so you could - in theory - do something like that:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("API", policy => {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(
            /* Scheme 1: */ JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            /* Scheme 2: */ typeof(IdentityCookieOptions).Namespace + ".Application");
    });
});
```

> Note: `typeof(IdentityCookieOptions).Namespace + ".Application"` is the
>   default authentication scheme used by ASP.NET Identity 3:
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/3.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs#L61

Alternatively, you could also remove the `policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes` call and configure the bearer and cookies middleware to use automatic authentication (`AutomaticAuthenticate = true`, which is the default value for the cookies middleware, but not for the JWT middleware).

---

In practice, it's absolutely **not recommended** as it defeats the whole purpose of using bearer-only authentication: mitigating XSRF attacks. If you really want to support cookies + bearer authentication, you **should strongly** consider implementing XSRF countermeasures.

Comment: In terms of technical guidance this is what I was looking for. 1 more question in terms of architecture, what is the best way to reuse code between mobile app web api and .net mvc web application? I will read more about XSRF, thank you.

Comment: do you think solution like shown in this answer may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken

Comment: Yep, that's an option. Note that in RC2, the cookies middleware will likely have a built-in antiforgery countermeasure, so maybe you should wait until the next RC: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/692.