# Kendo Upload - CSRF Token with ASP.NET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

From what I saw, Kendo upload sends the CSRF token in the POST request body. What am I trying to do is to validate this token when making the request to a Web API method, but can't seem to figure it out.

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there something specific that I should override or change?

Thanks.

Comment: did you use `ValidateAntiFogeryToken` attribute to decorate your web api action method?

Comment: Yes. And it's not working for me. Kendo upload sends the token in the POST request body, not in the headers.

Comment: Asked and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken).

Answer (score 0):

[see the anser](http://[see%20the%20anser][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988911/kendo-upload-csrf-token-with-kendo-ui-jquery/59044693#59044693)

```
<meta name="_token" content="csrf_token()" />

<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />

<script>
  var token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');  

$("#photos").kendoUpload({
async: {
    saveUrl: "http://url/save"
},
upload: onUpload
});

function onUpload(e) {
var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;
if (xhr) {
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 1 /* OPENED */) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token);
        }
    });
 }
}
</script>
```