# Kendo Upload - CSRF Token with kendo ui jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-upload

[how to add  CSRF Token in kendoUpload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K257u.png)

```
$("#image").kendoUpload({

    async: {
        saveUrl: "http://url",

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />

<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
```

```
   var token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');  

$("#photos").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "http://url/save"
    },
    upload: onUpload
});

function onUpload(e) {
    var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 1 /* OPENED */) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[document](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/upload?_ga=2.220187802.268655046.1574142452-608826626.1573988523)