# How to add CSRF token in kendo upload component?

Tags: kendo-ui

I know it was been answered but it's working in the latest version of kendo.
Is there another way to add a csrf token? I've been stock on this error in laravel.

[Kendo Upload - CSRF Token with kendo ui jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988911/kendo-upload-csrf-token-with-kendo-ui-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, my meta name is just in typo error.