# anti forgery token using rest client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman, antiforgerytoken

I have a mvc site and I use the  ValidateAntiForgeryToken on some of my action methods. On view I have the following line of code:

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

The problem starts when I tried to call the function using postman rest client. 
I get an error:

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is
>   not present.

I tried sending the cookies needed as such:
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=hgpv04mkuldbex45im3gco;  __RequestVerificationToken=2Of_03RzDacR4Hf-sWS3f_G0kZs1

But still getting the same error.
Anyone knows what the hell am I missing please?

Comment: do you really want to use the anti forgery token? If not just remove the  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute from the controller...

Comment: can you add your view ?

Comment: Are you interacting with a Web Api action? Web Api doesn't support cookies (since it is *REST-based* and *REST* doesn't support cookies). The `_RequestVerificationToken` must be provided as a header or in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

It is two part

Part 1 is to add to the cshtml

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Part 2 is to add this to the method

```
[HttpPost]  
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
public ActionResult CreateSomething(Something model)  
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)  
  {
    //your logic 
  }
  return View(ModelName);
}
```

Comment: part 3, if you are doing webApi -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476883/web-api-and-validateantiforgerytoken